# Is there a Java to SWF compiler?

Tags: java, air, flash

I am working on an Adobe AIR project that is in need of some Java libraries. I can make copies of them in AS3 but had the idea of what if there is a Java to SWF or even Java to SWC compiler available then I could use the Java ones and save time.

A Google search did not get far as all of the Java to SWF I saw were point of concept or very old.

Another cool thing about using Java to SWF could be the ability to use threads, because the ASVM2 supports them but AS3 does not.

Any ideas on if such a thing exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at :

http://www.flagstonesoftware.com/transform/

> Transform SWF Transform is an Open
>   Source library for reading and writing
>   Flash (.swf) files. The API gives you
>   complete control over how files are
>   created with access to all the
>   features supported by the Flash Player
>   but yet is still intuitive and easy to
>   use.
>
> **Key Features:**
>
> 1. **Full support **for Flash 10**.
> 2. Access to all of Flash giving full control of the Player.
> 3. Generate Flash files for any version of the desktop Flash
>      Player......etc

There is an older implementation: http://www.anotherbigidea.com/javaswf/